# Controllers <-> Services interaction and unit-testing : Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, service, controller

I'm building an **AngularJS** app, and I would it to be respectful or the best practices.
Thus, when I have to call an external *$resource* or *$http* request, I do it in an external **Service**/Factory.
My problem is I don't know what is the best way for retrieving returned value of the **Service** into the calling **Controller**.

Currently, what I do is the following :

1. The **controller** calls the **Service**
2. The **Service** does the *$http* call and check the *promise*.
3. If promise is successful, the **Service** *$broadcast* an event with the returned object.
4. The **Controller** *catches* that event and does operations.

It works great and allows me to use the same event after different requests (ex: In a discussion, after retrieving all messages and after posted myself a message, the same event "new messages to display" is called)

.

But I finally decided to set up **testing** processes in my application (better late than never), and I realize that I could do it wrong.

--> When unit-testing my Controllers I want to mock some of my **Services** for returning given values. But as my **Controller** calls **Services** which doesn't returns anything (they fire *events* instead) I think it will be pretty hard and not natural to check **Services** "return" values. (I can always check if the Service has been called, but not the result).

.

Your opinion, have I done misconception errors ? I consider getting the *promises* directly into Controllers when calling **Services**, is this a good (better?) way to do it ?

I aware that each application have its own logic, but I think in **AngularJS** the number of "working" logics (that preserves modularity, and testability) are particularly restricted to some set of choices and best practices.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your code, I have my ideas:

Your controller could receive that promise and do what it needs to do. There is no real need to broadcast anything. Your service call $http and then return the promise. When $http promise is resolved, your controller will know and can do what you need to do.

Testing functions in a service that doesn't return anything is not a problem, that is what `spyOn` is. You can check that the function has been called and that should be enough for your controller. You don't actually care what happens in the service, you cares about your controller (in the test controller, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use  events for such kind of interaction. They make a mess inside of the code and reduce maintainability. Sometimes you can use them but it is fine only for certain operations and for some specific situations. Using promises is good approach.

Here you have three different options:

- Just return the $http promise object and handle it inside of your controller
- Make your own promise with $q service and place inside of it your own logic for handling the response from $http or direct returning result (it is more flexible approach than the first one)
- Just pass to the services a function callback which you can call there inside of your service to pass the result back to controller.

But you definitely don't need to use events in these cases.

What is related to unit-testing you will configure $httpBackend service to mock your queries and in this case everything will work fine and you can test anything you need ([$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)). It means that you can inject your service and it works fine (as instead of real http call it will return the object configured as a response in the $httpBackend). So you can still test your controller without need to make anything complicated to your services.